# Custom animations in AQGridView cells happen instantly?

Tags: ios6, core-animation, aqgridview

So, I'm working with an AQGridView. We have custom cells with images in them. Now we want the images to bounce when clicked on. I tried operating on the frame of the image, but that didn't work so now I'm trying creating a UIImageView in the main view and giving that a path animation, but what ends up happening is the view just appears in the upper lefthand corder of the cell in question. Here's the relevant code.

```
-(void)bounce:(CoverGridCell*)v {
    UIView * w = [v.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImageView * u = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:v.image];
    u.frame = [self.view convertRect:[[w.subviews objectAtIndex:0] frame] fromView:w];
    double __block y = u.frame.origin.y;
    double __block x = u.frame.origin.x;
    [self.view addSubview:u];
    CGMutablePathRef cgmp = CGPathCreateMutable();for (int j= 10; j > 0;j--) {
        CGAffineTransform t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, - j*j);
        CGAffineTransform t2 = CGAffineTransformInvert(t1);
        CGPathMoveToPoint(cgmp,&t1, x, y - j * j);
        CGPathMoveToPoint(cgmp,&t2, x, y);
    }
    CGPathRef cgp = CGPathCreateCopy(cgmp);

    CGPathRelease(cgmp);

    CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"position"];
    anim.duration = 5.0;
    anim.delegate = self;
    anim.path = cgp;
    anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    [u.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"DoesThisMatter"];
    [u.layer setPosition:CGPointMake(x,y)];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a a threading issue, IIRC. The stuff that happened when a cell was clicked was freezing the 'Pad until the animation was over.